# How to combine array results of foreach inside of it

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to display all products from a wishlist, woocommerce plugin. Also, I want to make the wishlist sortable so I connect it to a db and if the row with the given unique ID is not there, it will display all the products by category unorganised.

If there is an unique ID then it should display all items there. Right now it displays the $row as the following:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 237 
    [1] => 243 
    [2] => 266 
) 
Array ( 
    [0] => 237 
    [1] => 243 
    [2] => 266 
) 
Array ( 
    [0] => 237 
    [1] => 243 
    [2] => 266 
)
```

Due to 3 products being in the same category, it displays them all 3 at once.

```
        <?php
        // db conn
        $mysqli = new mysqli(
            "localhost",
            "root",
            "root",
            "nest"
        );
        // new wishist
        $wishlist = new WC_Wishlists_Wishlist( $_GET['wlid'] );
        // get products from wishlist
        $wishlist_items = WC_Wishlists_Wishlist_Item_Collection::get_items( $wishlist->id, true );
        // counter - useless at the moment
        $counter = 0;
        // loop through all products
        foreach ( $wishlist_items as $wishlist_item_key => $item ) {
            $counter++;
            // get product id
            $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $item['product_id'], $item, $wishlist_item_key );
            // get categories
            $cats = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');

            // loop categories
            foreach ($cats as $cat) {
                // get slug
                $product_cat = $cat->slug;
            }
            // wishlist id is set in the database as a primary key - unique.
            $wlid_cats = $product_cat . $wishlist->id;

            // query with results
            $result = $mysqli->query("
                SELECT list 
                FROM sortable 
                WHERE wlid_cats = '$wlid_cats' "
            );

            // results parsed into $row
            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

            if (isset($row)) {
                // change string to array
                $row = implode(' ', $row);
                // split array item[0] into diff items.
                $row = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $row);
            }
            // get product data
            $_product   = wc_get_product( $item['data'] );
            if ( $_product->exists() && $item['quantity'] > 0 ) {
                $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $item ) : '', $item, $wishlist_item_key );
                // $cate is a function parameter which asks for the category to be displayed
                if  ($product_cat == $cate && empty($row)) {
                ?>
                        <!--Saved for Jquery reasons - POST to db-->
                        <p style="display: none" id="<?= $wishlist->id ?>"  class="<?= $wishlist->id ?> "><?= $cate ?></p>
                        <li class="product-thumbnail" type="<?= $cate ?>" id="product-<?= $product_id ?>">
                            <?php
                            // gets thumbnail and displays it 
                            $thumbnail = apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $item, $wishlist_item_key);
                            echo $wlid_cats;
                            if (!$product_permalink) {
                                echo $thumbnail;
                            } else {
                                printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url($product_permalink), $thumbnail);
                            }
                            ?>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                } elseif (!empty($row)) {

                    // where I'm stuck
                    print_r($row);

                }

            }
        } ?>
```

How can I merge the output to only get one array instead of 3?

Comment: use array_merge();

Comment: It would still display all of them together.

Comment: $result = array_unique($row);

Comment: It still outputs the same group of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make new global array

```
$narray = array();
```

and after that in your condition

```
elseif (!empty($row)) {
          // where I'm stuck
     $narray[] = $row; // add the array
}
$result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $narray)));
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Got it to work. However, it's outside the foreach loop from which I can't get the result of the $product_cat.

Comment: Got an error. Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values

Comment: $result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $narray)));

Comment: Output to that is Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 237 [1] => 243 [2] => 266 ) )

Comment: Not yet because the array is out of the first foreach loop which helped me get the categories so I can filter them by category. How would I get that to be outside the loop and associate itself?

Comment: Fixed it. I didn't need to get the category since I already had the numbers and I didn't need sorting. Thanks for your help Anand

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to work the problem here.
SHouldn't this query

```
$result = $mysqli->query("
                SELECT list 
                FROM sortable 
                WHERE wlid_cats = '$wlid_cats' "
                );
```

Have the list of categories not just one category, then if there are duplicates it'll sort it out.

Just re-reading your question and trying to figure this all out.

So on line 12 you've got ids of the items now you need to sort them by the 'sortable' table?

So a query (if this was just normal sql) would be something like this.

//itemIds for the order

```
$order = "itemId=3 DESC,itemId=1 DESC,itemId=5 DESC,itemId=6 DESC,category DESC";

  $query =  "SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemID IN (myItems) ORDER BY ".$order;
```

Maybe I've missed the point here, but the sql is sound.

Comment: Not quite sure how to implement your answer in.

Comment: So the order of the list is in the $row[list] element?

Comment: Use that to create the order element, by exploding or whatever and then you can select the items in the correct order, no fuss

Comment: Thank you for your input. I solved the problem using Anand's solution.

Comment: To reply to you, both Anand's solution and yours helped me do fix the issue. After getting the array with the order I just displayed all the items with the given ID. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, in the end when it comes to SQL, if you can reduce the amount of queries then you will have a quicker page (if only my milliseconds sometimes), and cleaner code. Which can only be a good things. Please vote up if you found my answer helpful.